# Angular2: using GUI JS libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I’m developing web app using Angular2. I use some external GUI libraries like: nanosSroller , qTip2. Problem is that some of them requires initialization like:

`$('.panel').nanoScroller();`

I’m not sure where to put this code. In my opinion best place would be  tag in template file because this code is strictly view related but Angular2 removes all  tags from templates so it’s not possible. I’ve ended up with custom service that is used inside `ngAfterViewInit`:

`ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.jsInitializer.initializeScroll('#user-panel');
 }`

I like this approach because I keep all GUI libraries dependencies in single service. What I don’t like about it is that I still have to pass manually css selector. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I don't see any issues for passing the CSS selector, is what the third party library needs. I'm doing the same thing.

Comment: I just don’t like to keep view specific information in controller. Every time I change view I have to remember to validate CSS selectors in controller :/

Comment: yeah, definitely it is not the angular2 way, but we already using third party libraries which is not the angular2 way of doing things :)